# Implementing window scrolling to switch between videos using Vue 3 composition API

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I am fetching an array of videos from the database and displaying them on the homepage using the index of the videos. Each video is displayed with a height of 100vh, and there is a button with an upward arrow to decrement the video index by 1, as well as a button with a downward arrow to increment the video index by 1. This allows me to switch between the videos based on their index.
Now I want to replace the buttons with window scrolling. How can the DOM determine whether I am scrolling down to increment or up to decrement the video index?
By the way I am using Vue 3 with composition API

the code is here:

```html
<video
  @click="handleScroll"
  v-if="index === currentVideoIndex"
  loop
  autoplay
  class="video"
  :ref="getVideoRef(index)"
  :data-index="index"
>
  <source class="source" :src="video.url" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

`<script setup>`:

```js
const currentVideoIndex = ref(0)

const handleScroll = () => {
  currentVideoIndex.value++
  if (currentVideoIndex.value >= videos.value.length) {
    currentVideoIndex.value = 0
  }

  currentVideoId.value = videos.value[currentVideoIndex.value]._id
}
```

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/6h0742sp/) should do it. You might want to debounce it (scroll can happen a lot of times / second).